# Fetching rows based on different criteria and weights with hierarchy

Tags: sql

I have this table:

| ID | Weight1 | Weight2 | Weight3 | GroupFrom | GroupTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 50 | A | Z |
| 2 | 20 | 0 | 0 | A | Y |
| 3 | 0 | 25 | 0 | B | W |
| 4 | 0 | 25 | 0 | B | W |
| 5 | 0 | 25 | 0 | B | V |

I want to be able to pick just 1 GroupTo per GroupFrom based on the weight where Weight1 takes the most priority, followed by Weight2 and Weight3. In the event there's a tie, it will pick GroupTo that's more frequent.

So the expected output is:

| ID | GroupFrom | GroupTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | Y |
| 3 | B | W |
| 4 | B | W |

The current approach I have is to isolate the one-to-many records and evaluate the three weights separately with dense rank like below:

```
select * 
into #Staging1
from
(
select *, dense_rank() over (partition by GroupFrom order by Weight1 desc) as rank from #temp
) t
where rank = 1

select * 
into #Staging2
from
(
select *, dense_rank() over (partition by GroupFrom order by Weight2 desc) as rank2 from #Staging1
) t
where rank2 = 1
```

And finally use the count function at the end as a tie breaker if there's still one-to-many records.

The solution sort of works but I'm looking to find a more efficient way of doing this if there's any. Appreciate any ideas or new approaches. I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `RANK()` here along with an order by clause which sorts using the three weights.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupFrom
                           ORDER BY Weight1 DESC, Weight2 DESC, Weight3 DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, GroupFrom, GroupTo
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY GroupFrom, GroupTo;
```